# Using Bootstrap Affix from JS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Affix scroll page to element, when user click element with link to him. But, How I can trigger this action from JS code?
Like this.

```
$("#id").navigate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this:

```
$('#id').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 200
    }
});
```

or:

```
$('#id').affix({
    offset: $('#other-id').position()
});
```

Just check the documentation page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

**EDIT**

If you want to *trigger* a navigate, it should be the same a triggering a click on a link inside an affix. Example, try clicking on 'Test ClickAffix' link in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/df8tb/911/

Here is the code:

```
$('#nav').affix({
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anylink').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#affixedLink1').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: As I understand, this code activates the navigation elements on the page through the navigation menu. I would like to get the same result is obtained by Cator clicking on the menu item, that is - to scroll requiring elements.

Comment: @Aminion I have updated my answer. Check this out if this helps you.